# Can't find window C++

Tags: c++, window

I am writing a code that needs to access a memory file in the game dead Island but the problem is when i run the code it says that it is unable to find the window. I have tried with other programs and it works. I have tried the name that it is in task manager and it still does not work. Here is my code
    `HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Dead Island - Definitive Edition");`

Comment: I have also tried using spy++ it comes up with the same name as it does normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mode 1** : Use `::FindWindowEx()`

**Mode 2** : Get window handle from exe name(! Set exe name of Dead Island)

```
TCHAR* szExeName = _T("Dead Island"); //Dead Island.exe

HANDLE GetHandleOfDeadIsland()
{
    HANDLE hDeadIsland = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE hSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hSnap)
    {
        if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe32))
        {
            do 
            {
                //!!! Attention pe32.szExeFile always return exe file name. not window title.
                if (NULL != _tcsstr(pe32.szExeFile, szExeName))
                {
                    hDeadIsland = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32));
        }
    }

    return hDeadIsland;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hDeadIsland = GetHandleOfDeadIsland();
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hDeadIsland)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Not Found\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Found\n"));
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that the dead island exe is called "Dead Island" and not "DeadIsland.exe" ?